# What is wrong in my DKIM setup? I'm getting all fails

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, dkim, domainkeys, dmarc

I own a domain name

I have implemented SPF and DKIM to avoid my mails being junked. I have also upgraded to DMARC in monitor mode.

Since I received a few failure reports recently I wanted to investigate more. I have only one server sending outbound emails, running `postfix` + `dkimproxy`. I trust that dkimproxy has no major software bugs resulting in bad messages.

I have tested [ReturnPath](https://www.returnpath.com)'s automated DKIM test and this is the part related to DKIM/DomainKeys

```
DKIM Results
============
Result =  failed: invalid key for signature: Syntax error in tag: \"v
Domain = domain.org
Selector = sel
DNS Record(s) =
    sel._domainkey.domain.org TXT "v=1; p=MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAsMMLhxzXkU+tagc44oMi7eX2BsFb8BsWeT8MRL+hxi4Lsosx7tuPm90iYgilNteyJoXuSP5SUf8B2tDAifdzYQhfhctr0hX9b6ocBCukGq5p0GHpNsCPWyFvxZsCkGqLRmkfb0c36quEAWBeQLe4Z/BwXBBiW1g96WFNb2/GRI1+9OHhligdfuo4PPuU+xiwX4GB0Ik50cJL4xTdBf7lrFwoGYa03ZkXuzKxeGE4cTk50OeIs6eqrzAfbmej4nCex2qGOUt1TWI7ZvCY7u3Gxj+XKaE7VFrQACZof+NP0k2pXPHg9saGJqZrr2i6+RoxGD0w/ibjAWij9enwqlnv2ORsZfe+FmXNOLJAhlYvhHaruubDpte1c7V3ZKDceM45ZawnVmSdLCfBrMbsqipzy8NXN5MxuANYFBkx5EDT+Ieab+zqcnf08m9bgDc4RXMYppDT1/lUy6On+nyfZEnJWiH3BUtgxS8X0uXciXbsooTmPnpkzzvvKXAE/Tv3XqL90q51geqP0EmaZI6lRTpiqoX7zFGlEBiiF7/u8oheszATks8LsNZ/boTFy0OVldbYNhxlIuRmqeXkqD6+kM5ObKtMEv3AdaeBiZmvyJTP8tCsSmPt+e954RLlz2HaDjjNnZNgsj/39U2RzZsFbVqW6uyQh36/y1X4joOiPf366GkCAwEAAQ==; t=s"
    Public Key Length = 4096

DomainKeys Results
==================
Domain = domain.org
Selector = sel
DNS Record(s) =
    sel._domainkey.domain.org TXT "v=1; p=MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAsMMLhxzXkU+tagc44oMi7eX2BsFb8BsWeT8MRL+hxi4Lsosx7tuPm90iYgilNteyJoXuSP5SUf8B2tDAifdzYQhfhctr0hX9b6ocBCukGq5p0GHpNsCPWyFvxZsCkGqLRmkfb0c36quEAWBeQLe4Z/BwXBBiW1g96WFNb2/GRI1+9OHhligdfuo4PPuU+xiwX4GB0Ik50cJL4xTdBf7lrFwoGYa03ZkXuzKxeGE4cTk50OeIs6eqrzAfbmej4nCex2qGOUt1TWI7ZvCY7u3Gxj+XKaE7VFrQACZof+NP0k2pXPHg9saGJqZrr2i6+RoxGD0w/ibjAWij9enwqlnv2ORsZfe+FmXNOLJAhlYvhHaruubDpte1c7V3ZKDceM45ZawnVmSdLCfBrMbsqipzy8NXN5MxuANYFBkx5EDT+Ieab+zqcnf08m9bgDc4RXMYppDT1/lUy6On+nyfZEnJWiH3BUtgxS8X0uXciXbsooTmPnpkzzvvKXAE/Tv3XqL90q51geqP0EmaZI6lRTpiqoX7zFGlEBiiF7/u8oheszATks8LsNZ/boTFy0OVldbYNhxlIuRmqeXkqD6+kM5ObKtMEv3AdaeBiZmvyJTP8tCsSmPt+e954RLlz2HaDjjNnZNgsj/39U2RzZsFbVqW6uyQh36/y1X4joOiPf366GkCAwEAAQ==; t=s"
```

The mail displays an anonymised DNS record with genuine public key. It reports an error in tag `v`. A few hours ago I noticed my `v` tag was `v=DKIM1` instead of `v=1` as specified in RFC. I thought it was an error made by me during the initial setup months ago and fixed to `v=1`, but anyway I received one DMARC success from Google.

Let me explain better: I enforced DMARC a couple of days ago. On 4/16 morning I got a mail from Google telling me that DMARC fully passes, then since 4/17 I get all failures. Then I discovered the `v=DKIM1` tag and replaced with `v=1` without success

I have **not** modified my DNS records before that.

So, keeping in topic with the question, **why does ReturnPath refuse my DKIM DNS record**? Is something wrong in my DKIM implementation at DNS level?

[Add] I have just tried port25.com's tester but at least DKIM passes

```
----------------------------------------------------------
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         permerror (DK_STAT_BADKEY: Unusable key, public if verifying, private if signing.)
ID(s) verified: header.From=###########
DNS record(s):
    sel._domainkey.domain.org. 1800 IN TXT ""v=1; p=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; t=s""

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass (matches From: #########)
ID(s) verified: header.d=domain.org
Canonicalized Headers:
    message-id:<516FBF8A.9050702@domain.org>'0D''0A'
    date:Thu,'20'18'20'Apr'20'2013'20'11:40:26'20'+0200'0D''0A'
    from:#############'0D''0A'
    mime-version:1.0'0D''0A'
    to:check-auth@verifier.port25.com'0D''0A'
    subject:Test'0D''0A'
    content-type:text/plain;'20'charset=ISO-8859-15;'20'format=flowed'0D''0A'
    content-transfer-encoding:7bit'0D''0A'
    dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha1;'20'c=relaxed;'20'd=domain.org;'20'h='20'message-id:date:from:mime-version:to:subject:content-type'20':content-transfer-encoding;'20's=dom;'20'bh=uoq1oCgLlTqpdDX/iUbLy7J1Wi'20'c=;'20'b=

Canonicalized Body:
    '0D''0A'


DNS record(s):
    sel._domainkey.domain.org. 1800 IN TXT ""v=1; p=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; t=s""

Public key used for verification: sel._domainkey.domain.org (4096 bits)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the problem by chance: my DKIM DNS record contained **quotes**. It was a bad copy&paste.

Perhaps some providers automatically ignore quotes, while others do not.